# What is the file timestamp file stored?

Tags: metadata

what is the information stored, about creating, modified, last open, and the permission store in a file? How can I get this information?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in [`inode`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) and can be retrived by [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) call